# Parse error for one row (all the other rows work!)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set up a function that should update formulas based on the contents of a cell.  The code runs, however, for one row I keep getting a parse error message.  A snippet of the code is below:

```
ta2020 = ctlSheet.getRange("B19:K19");
efg2020 = ctlSheet.getRange("B20:K20");
decTA2020 = ctlSheet.getRange("B21:K21");
fft502020 = ctlSheet.getRange("B23:K23");

ta2020.setFormula("=countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$b$3,TA_20,B$18"); 
efg2020.setFormula("=countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$B$3,EFG_20,B$18)"); 
decTA2020.setFormula("=countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$B$3,DecMock_20,B$18)"); 
fft502020.setFormula("=countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$b$3,FFT50_20,B$18)");
```

The offending line is the ta2020.setFormula one.  All the other lines are fine, however, for this one the cell reference does not seem to update as it moves on to the next column so cell c19 should read =countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$b$3,TA_20,**C**$18, however, it seems to be stuck on =countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$b$3,TA_20,**B**$18.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are missing a `)` bracket

The correct syntax would be

`ta2020.setFormula("=countifs(Subject20,$B$1,Ethnicity2020,$b$3,TA_20,B$18)");`

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka can't believe I missed that!